# How to fix: tvOS xibs do not support target device type homepod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, tvos

I'm in the process of migration the codebase to Xcode 11.4. I've encountered the following error while compiling the tvOS application.

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
ErrorManager.xib: error: tvOS xibs do not support target device type "homepod".
```

Interesting thing is that **HomePod** is mentioned... Have anyone encountered a similar error? Do you have any ideas on how it might be solved? This xib compiles without any issues in Xcode 11.1